# How to avoid flickering while the CScrollView is moving?

Tags: c++, mfc

I was trying to make the CScrollView move

Although it moved successfully, but I found a problem...

The CScrollView flickered randomly while it is moving.

Below is the whole code of my project:

```
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <afxext.h> 
#include "resource.h"

class MyView : public CScrollView
{
public:
    void OnDraw(CDC *aDC){
        CRect rc;
        GetClientRect(&rc);

        aDC->FillSolidRect(&rc, RGB(0,0,255));
    }

    BOOL PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)  
    {  
        cs.style &= ~WS_BORDER;
        return CScrollView::PreCreateWindow(cs);  
    } 

    afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
    {
        if(CScrollView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
            return -1;
        CSize DCSize(200, 800);

        SetScrollSizes(MM_TEXT, DCSize);
        return 0;
    }


    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(MyView)
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(MyView, CScrollView)

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyView, CScrollView)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

class CMainDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    CMainDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);

    enum { IDD = IDD_MAIN_DIALOG };

    CWnd* pFrameWnd;
    CCreateContext context;
    MyView* pView;
    int time;

    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnTimer(UINT_PTR timer);

    void OnPaint(){
        CPaintDC dc(this);
        CRect rc;
        GetClientRect(&rc);
        dc.FillSolidRect(&rc,RGB(255,187,187));
    }


    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainDlg, CDialog)
    ON_WM_TIMER()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


CMainDlg::CMainDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CMainDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
}


BOOL CMainDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
   CDialog::OnInitDialog();

   pFrameWnd = this;
   context.m_pCurrentDoc = NULL;
   context.m_pNewViewClass = RUNTIME_CLASS(MyView);

   pView = (MyView*)((CFrameWnd*)pFrameWnd)->CreateView(&context);
   pView->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

   time = 0;
   SetTimer(1, 1, 0);
   return TRUE;
}

void CMainDlg::OnTimer(UINT_PTR timer)
{
    if(timer == 1){
        if(time > 300){
            KillTimer(1);
            return;
        }
        pView->MoveWindow(CRect(time,10,time+300,200),FALSE);
    }
    time+=1;
    Invalidate(FALSE);
}
class MyApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        CWinApp::InitInstance();

        CMainDlg Frame;

        Frame.DoModal();

        return true;
    }
} a_app;
```

I don't know why the CScrollView flickered while it is moving. Can anyone solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is flickering because you're invalidating the entire window.  This causes a WM_ERASE, which blanks the window, then a WM_PAINT, which redraws the entire thing.  You're passing `FALSE` as the `bRepaint` (last) parameter to `MoveWindow`, so that it won't repaint any necessary window area after the window has been moved.

Normally when a window moves the content moves with it, and the only parts that need to be redrawn are bits that were offscreen or under another window.  Passing `TRUE` as the last parameter will cause only these areas of the window to be redrawn, which will avoid the flicker.

Comment: The call to [CWnd::Invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ax04k970.aspx) passes `FALSE` as the *bErase* argument.